# fields_for belongs_to model, custom nested fields -- form error messages not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create nested fields for the sender to which an order belongs I am unable to see any error messages when the form is incorrectly filled.

orders.rb -- model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "Client"
    belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "Client"
end
```

clients.rb -- model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :first_name
end
```

new.erb.html -- the form

```
<% form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
...
    <% fields_for :sender do |s| %>
      <%= s.error_messages %>
      <p>
        <%= s.label :telephone, "Phone number" %><br />
      </p>

...
```

I am not using accepts_nested_attributes_for, as it did not work for my belongs_to models.
I have already created the required form fields and the controller that I need for saving the data which I need.

How can I display the error messages for the sender and recipient?

I am using Ruby On Rails 2.3.11

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my post on something similar, I think it might answer your question: http://jedschneider.posterous.com/validation-messages-on-associated-attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the client when you save an order, you can do the following:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "Client", :validate => true
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "Client", :validate => true
end
```

If you're trying to validate orders when the client is saved you can do the following:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :validate => true
end
```

And if for some reason those don't work for you, it would be helpful if you explained the reason why. You alluded that you can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but I assume you still are using associations — otherwise I'm not sure what you would be validating.

Comment: after I have added your suggestions,  <%= s.error_messages %> still does not return anything

Comment: @denysonique Ahh I didn't catch that you were using Rails 2 still; you might need to use `validates_associated`. Check the apidock reference page for it here: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: I tried with a new line: validates_associated :clients, and other combinations with no luck